# How can the result of that limit be expressed completely?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to find the expression of the following limit:

```
Limit[Power[1 + RealAbs[x]^(3 n), (n)^-1], n -> Infinity]
(* ConditionalExpression[1, (x >= 0\[And]log(x)<0)\[Or](x<0\[And]log(-x)<0)] *)
```

But the result is not complete. The reference answer is $f(x)=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{1+|x|^{3 n}}=\left\{\begin{array}{c}
1,|x| \leq 1 \\
|x|^{3},|x|>1
\end{array}\right.$.

What can I do to get the full expression?

Answer (score 5):

Let us consider the opposite case by

```
Limit[Power[1 + RealAbs[x]^(3 n), (n)^-1], n -> Infinity, 
 Assumptions -> (x >= 0 && Log[x] >= 0) || (x < 0 && Log[-x] >= 0)]
```

$$\text{ConditionalExpression}\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 -x^3 & x<0 \\
 x^3 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
,x<0\lor \log (x)>0\right] $$
It remains to consider the case `RealAbs[x]==1`:

```
Limit[Power[1 + RealAbs[x]^(3 n), (n)^-1] /. RealAbs[x] -> 1, n -> Infinity]
```

$1$